# Experiencing error setup up Google Earth Engine web app client side

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to follow the guide provided here [Google Earth Engine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lg5JK.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lg5JK.png): https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/custom-apps/client-js to set GEE on the browser. I copied the code strictly as it has been provided. I am getting an unknown error popup with an empty console. See the image below
[image]

Here is the code snippet

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/earthengine/0.1.365/earthengine-api.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      /* Set the size of the div element that contains the map. */
      #map-container {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #eee;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- The "Sign in with Google" button, initially hidden. -->
    <input
      id="g-sign-in"
      type="image"
      src="https://developers.google.com/identity/images/btn_google_signin_light_normal_web.png"
      onclick="onSignInButtonClick()"
      alt="Sign in with Google"
      hidden
    />

    <!-- Element where map will be added. -->
    <div id="map-container"></div>
    <script>
      // The OAuth Client ID from the Google Developers Console.
      const CLIENT_ID = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
      
      // Initializes Maps JavaScript API and Earth Engine API, instructing the map
      // to pull tiles from Earth Engine and to overlay them on the map.
      function setUpMap() {
        // Hide the sign-in button.
        document.getElementById("g-sign-in").setAttribute("hidden", "true");
      
        // Initialize the Earth Engine API. Must be called once before using the API.
        ee.initialize();
      
        // Get a reference to the placeholder DOM element to contain the map.
        const mapContainerEl = document.getElementById("map-container");
      
        // Create an interactive map inside the placeholder DOM element.
        const embeddedMap = new google.maps.Map(mapContainerEl, {
          // Pan and zoom initial map viewport to Grand Canyon.
          center: {lng: -112.8598, lat: 36.2841},
          zoom: 9,
        });
      
        // Obtain reference to digital elevation model and apply algorithm to
        // calculate slope.
        const srtm = ee.Image("CGIAR/SRTM90_V4");
        const slope = ee.Terrain.slope(srtm);
      
        // Create a new tile source to fetch visible tiles on demand and display them
        // on the map.
        const mapId = slope.getMap({min: 0, max: 60});
        const tileSource = new ee.layers.EarthEngineTileSource(mapId);
        const overlay = new ee.layers.ImageOverlay(tileSource);
        embeddedMap.overlayMapTypes.push(overlay);
      }
      
      // Handles clicks on the sign-in button.
      function onSignInButtonClick() {
        // Display popup allowing the user to sign in with their Google account and to
        // grant appropriate permissions to the app.
        ee.data.authenticateViaPopup(setUpMap);
      }
      
      // If the user is signed in, display a popup requesting permissions needed to
      // run the app, otherwise show the sign-in button.
      ee.data.authenticateViaOauth(
        // The OAuth Client ID defined above.
        CLIENT_ID,
        // Callback invoked immediately when user is already signed in.
        setUpMap,
        // Show authentication errors in a popup.
        alert,
        // Request permission to only read and compute Earth Engine data on behalf of
        // user.
        /* extraScopes = */ ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/earthengine.readonly'],
        // Show sign-in button if reusing existing credentials fails.
        () => document.getElementById("g-sign-in").removeAttribute("hidden"),
        // Don't require ability to write and access Cloud Platform on behalf of the
        // user.
        /* opt_suppressDefaultScopes = */ true
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```